# iPad 4 cannot connect to internet using iMac wireless

Tags: ipad, wifi, imac, internet

Have latest iPad 4 and latest iMac with OS Lion and have a wireless connection. iMac system preferences checked for internet sharing ethernet to wireless device. BUT iPad Safari cannot open page as unable to connect to internet. The iMac ethernet connection is via Cable and internet connection ok. Any advice as to how to connect the iPad correctly. I've tried re-start after checking all settings are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already follow the instructions at http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3853

And this thread discusses a variety of configuration problems that some people have had http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1192376

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes deleting the network interface and adding it again solves the problem.